# Generating sql insert into for DataGrip

Tags: insert, sql-insert, datagrip

When you run a query (a SELECT statement) in the console, the data retrieved from the database are shown in table format in the Result pane of the Database Console tool window.

I've searched through [datagrip Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/viewing-query-results.html) and I'm just wondering if there is anyway out there that can be used to generate INSERT INTO scripts for a tables' content or rows in table format?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Choose SQL Insert extractor in the drop-down menu.

[image]

Them you'll be able to copy (Ctrl/Cmd+C) data as a bunch of INSERTS. Or use *Export* button next to the extractor.

[image]

Comment: than you, can I generate insert for one (or some) of the rows in the Result pane (table format) or I must specify that row in where clause?

Comment: Yes you can, just select this row and press Copy. Only this row will be generated.

Comment: Note if you don't see a "SQL Inserts" button, click on the drop down to the left of the "download" button , and then you can choose "SQL Inserts". Mine was defaulted to something else originally...

Comment: For those who are trying to find a way to do batch inserts, this should work: https://gist.github.com/ProjectCleverWeb/d2362b082af1d7054ebfd464f202ec1b